# In docker, Why I can not see any intermediate images when build an image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The docker docs said:

> The Docker daemon runs the instructions in the Dockerfile one-by-one, committing the result of each instruction to a new image if necessary, before finally outputting the ID of your new image. The Docker daemon will automatically clean up the context you sent.

So against the quote above, my question is below:

1. When is it necessary to commit the result of one instruction to a new image?
2. If the new images is generated, why I can not see any new image except the final image when finishing the build process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As a Dockerfile author, you never need to manually commit anything.  Almost every Dockerfile instruction results in a new layer; the only exceptions I can think of are FROM (which starts a new stage in a multi-stage build) and maybe ARG (documented to "not persist into the built image").
2. `docker images` doesn't display images that don't have tags but do have additional images built on top of them.  `docker images -a` will display everything.  It's usually an implementation detail, though, and the long list of `<none>` images tends to be more a source of confusion.

   Also note that intermediate image IDs are printed out by `docker build` as it executes each step, and you should also be able to find them via `docker history`.  Running `docker run` on an intermediate image is a pretty useful debugging technique if you can tell the input to some step isn't right but you're not sure why.